# Mysql Deadlock on table that has autogenerated primary key and unique key

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I have a table sdr with an autogenerated primary key and a unique key. Randomly I get these deadlock errors as shown below. It is a hibernate based web application firing these insert queries.
After reading mysql documentation on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html, it seems it could be resolved using READ_COMMITTED. Incidentally, the database is already set to tx_isolation = READ-COMMITTED.

I cannot remove the unique key because the business logic needs to check if the record already exists. Also, UI provides the unique key values for read operations.

I also cannot remove the auto generated primary column due to downstream application impacts.

**Can this issue be fixed with the stated constraints?**

More details:
Mysql 5.6 InnoDB

**TABLE  statement:**

```
     CREATE TABLE `sdr` (   
        `s_d_r_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
        `fk_d_r_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,   
        `fk_s_s_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,   
        `t_l_x_no` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,   
        `t_l_y_no` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,   
        `h_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   
        `w_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   
        `o_tx` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,   
        `f_d_c_tx` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,   
        `l_c_no` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
         `d_in` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   
        `c_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
         `c_u_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,   
        `l_m_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 05:00:00',  
         `l_m_user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,  
         `r_no` decimal(3,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
         PRIMARY KEY (`s_d_r_id`),   
        UNIQUE KEY `uk_s_d_r` (`fk_d_r_id`,`fk_s_s_id`,`t_l_x_no`,`t_l_y_no`,`r_no`),   
    KEY `i_s_fk_s_s_id` (`fk_s_s_id`),   
        CONSTRAINT `r_d_s` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_d_r_id`) 
        REFERENCES `d_r` (`D_R_ID`)  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION, 
  CONSTRAINT `r_s_s` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_s_s_id`) 
    REFERENCES `s_s` (`s_s_id`) 
         ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION ) 
        ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45904 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Deadlock log:**

```
    2015-10-11 09:25:18 7f30cb700700InnoDB: transactions deadlock detected,
 dumping detailed information.
        2015-10-11 09:25:18 7f30cb700700
        *** (1) TRANSACTION:
        TRANSACTION 276584110286, ACTIVE 1 sec inserting
        mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
        LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 2 row lock(s), 
    undo log entries 1
        MySQL thread id 31640, OS thread handle 0x7f3510eff700, query id 
    1796766867 server-1 21.222.12.123 db_user update
        insert into S_D_R (
    D_IN, L_C_NO, C_TS, C_U_ID, L_M_TS, L_M_U_ID, 
    F_D_C_TX, FK_D_R_ID, H_NO, FK_S_S_ID, O_TX, 
    T_L_X_NO, T_L_Y_NO, W_NO) values 
    (0, 0, '2015-10-11 13:25:18.036', 123, '2015-10-11 13:25:18.036', 
    123, '[]', 1234567, -1, 3, 'some', 555, 678, -1)
        *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
        RECORD LOCKS space id 4577 page no 9296 n bits 528 index 
    `uk_s_d_r` of table `test`.`s_d_r` trx id 276584110286 
    lock mode S waiting
        *** (2) TRANSACTION:
        TRANSACTION 276584110033, ACTIVE 1 sec inserting
        mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
        7 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 9 row lock(s),
     undo log entries 7
        MySQL thread id 32293, OS thread handle 0x7f30cb700700, 
    query id 1796767643 server-2 21.222.12.124 db_user update
        insert into S_D_R (
    D_IN, L_C_NO, C_TS, C_U_ID, L_M_TS, L_M_U_ID, 
    F_D_C_TX, FK_D_R_ID, H_NO, FK_S_S_ID, O_TX, T_L_X_NO, 
    T_L_Y_NO, W_NO) values (0, 0, '2015-10-11 13:25:18.081', 123, 
    '2015-10-11 13:25:18.081', 123, '[]', 6789064, -1, 7, 
    'someother', 550, 15, -1)
        *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
        RECORD LOCKS space id 4577 page no 9296 n bits 528 index 
    `uk_s_d_r` of table `test`.`s_d_r` trx id 276584110033 
    lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
        *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
        RECORD LOCKS space id 4577 page no 9296 n bits 536 index 
    `uk_s_d_r` of table `test`.`s_d_r` trx id 276584110033 
    lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
        *** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some more code of your insert / update statements would be helpful to determine if concurrency is being done properly and released when completed.  It appears that something is holding onto the database when the next call comes in.  Are these being done in Transactions or single statements?

Comment: The insert statements are within a transaction. The two transactions above have come from different servers. "locks gap before rec" in the log indicates that mysql performed a lock on the current unique index and  all future ranges. As per mysql gaplock documentation, this is necessary. It could be eliminated if we remove the unique index or the auto generated key. Since I cannot do either, I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: The code needs to check for deadlocks and retry the transaction.